# Uploading Project Data

Tags: usaidopen

I'm trying to upload project datasets (survey data). I have 30 to 40 excel files. They're not all formatted exactly the same way, because the survey design and platform were changed a few times during the project lifecycle. Can I simply drag these into the upload field? When I tried this with multiple files, DDL seems only to be previewing one of the files.

Answer (score -1):

We have received your request and a member of our team will email you shortly to help you troubleshoot.

Best wishes,
Data Services Team
dataservices@usaid.gov

Comment: this is not an answer @mdaniels. please respond with an answer that other users can use/learn from.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to upload multiple dataset files to one dataset page. You will need to set up a separate dataset page for each individual dataset file in order for all of them to ingest on the DDL. Otherwise, you will only see the most recently uploaded file.  Our [User Guide](https://data.usaid.gov/stories/s/ncfa-rh2w) describes the process.